# How to add two cells(strings) in excel based on a logic of some other cells?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel file with two different sheets. In Sheet 1, I have two columns (`A` and `B`). Sheet 2 has a single column(`M`) which contains repeated values from `A` columns.

Now I want to a add a new column(`N`) in sheet 2 which will contain values from column `B` based on whether A[i] == B[i] then put N[i] = B[i].

I tried excel formulas but could not do it. Do I need to write a macro?

In short I want is this ..

SHEET 1 -- Column A (several names unique values)  and Column B (phone number unique values)

SHEET 2 -- Column M (several names from A contains duplicates)

I want to add a new column in SHEET 2 (Column N) which will be like

`match M*i* == A*i* and put N*i* = B*i*`

Comment: You want VLOOKUP()

Comment: you could also do index/match for this, (beyond Scott's suggestion of VLOokup)... `=index(Sheet1!$B:$B,match(Sheet2!M1,Sheet1!$A:$A,0))`, which is aligned with your "match"

Answer (score 0):

As Scott said you're looking for a VLOOKUP() formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(M1,Sheet1!A:B,2,FALSE)
```

Copy the formula above in cell N1 and copy it to the column N.

Comment: I tried this now, it throws an exception error, says wrong reference, I double checked it.

Comment: It works well in my example, review the name of the Sheet, if it's not "Sheet1" just change it

Comment: Will it work if the values in M1 are referenced values(result of =concat() ) ?

Comment: That shouldn't be an issue. Please, post a screenshot of the spreadsheet so we can see what's wrong